# How to store database values in string?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have selected rows from database using

```
SELECT TOP 7 TID FROM historyinsert ORDER BY TID ASC
```

Now I have to store these 7 values in string. But I am confused how to achieve.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: You use Spring or another framework or not?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "I have to store these 7 values in string": one string for all, a string per value, etc. It also doesn't hurt to include the code you already have.

Comment: @JatinDogra: the Stackoverflow community is not at your disposal. "Reply asap!" is something not even the bossiest superior would dare to write – there is always time for adding a "please", at least. Be polite and people will be much eager to answer.

Comment: Ok sorry for that sir. It would never happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can list the result in an arraylist like this

```
res = conect.prepareStatement("SELECT something FROM historyinsert ORDER BY TID ASC").executeQuery();

ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
while (res.next()) {
    list.add(res.getString("something"));   
} 

String[] result = new String[list.size()];
result = list.toArray(result);

for(int i =0; i<result.length; i++){
    System.out.println(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: After printing these values can you tell how to store each value in a string

Comment: your values are stored in a string array `result[]` you can access it like this result[0],result[1],..

Answer (score 0):

SQL code:

```
DECLARE @numbers varchar(MAX)
SET @numbers = ''
SELECT  TOP 2  @numbers = @numbers + CAST(Id as nvarchar) + '-' FROM dbo.Person
SELECT @numbers;
```

the result is:  "1-2-"

for removing "-" change the last select statement like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@numbers, 0, len(@numbers));
```

the result is:  "1-2"